# Python regenerating ARMA params using statsmodels

Tags: python, arima

I am trying to regenerate the ARMA parameters from statsmodel in python. The code I am using is:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_process import arma_generate_sample
import statsmodels.api as sm
arparams = np.array([.75, -.25])
maparams = np.array([.65, .35])
arparams = np.r_[1, -arparams]
maparam = np.r_[1, maparams]
nobs = 250
np.random.seed(2014)
y = arma_generate_sample(arparams, maparams, nobs) #generate ARMA series
res = sm.tsa.arma_order_select_ic(y, ic=['aic', 'bic'], trend='nc')
z = sm.tsa.ARMA(y, (2,2)).fit()
print z.arparams
array([ 0.13178508,  0.08568388])
```

The regenerated AR params are not same as the one I started with. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic of your code is all right. However, the variance of the parameters is high because `nobs=250` is relatively low. Increase `nobs` and your parameters will converge toward the parameters you specified eventually.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

# Parameters.
ar = np.array([.75, -.25])
ma = np.array([.65, .35])

# Simulate an ARMA process.
np.random.seed(42)
y = sm.tsa.arma_generate_sample(
    ar=np.r_[1, -ar],
    ma=np.r_[1, ma],
    nsample=10000,
    sigma=1,
)

# Fit ARMA process on the simulates to check coefficients, ACF and PACF.
model = sm.tsa.ARMA(y, (2, 2)).fit(trend='c')

# Plot ACF and PACF of estimated model.
sm.tsa.graphics.plot_acf(y, lags=20, zero=True);
sm.tsa.graphics.plot_pacf(y, lags=20, zero=True);
model.summary()
```

Reference: [McKinney, W., Perktold, J., & Seabold, S. (2011)](https://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/scipy2011/pdfs/statsmodels.pdf)